# JS equivalent of Python request

Tags: javascript, python, api, python-requests, spotify

I am requesting a response from Spotify API.  All I need to know is how to get this python script statement into js.  What should I use in java that is like requests in python

```
query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{}/tracks?uris=. 
     {}".format(created_playlist, tracks);
```

```
response = requests.post(query, {"headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(token3)}})
```

Answer (score 1):

For Javascript, ES6+, use the native fetch API to perform REST HTTP requests,
alternative is the npm axios library, check its documentation

Comment: it causes CORS error

Comment: @datonefaridze can you check if you have a restricted cors whitelist, or if the request headers are correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fetch API its a promise based function different from python requests module

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

here are the docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: it causes CORS error